# Nvidia on Linux: "Codec h264_cuvid is not supported"

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, nvidia

I [configured FFMPEG to use Nvidia](https://docs.nvidia.com/video-technologies/video-codec-sdk/ffmpeg-with-nvidia-gpu/index.html), but when I try [this command](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/nvidia-ffmpeg-transcoding-guide/)

`ffmpeg -vsync 0 -hwaccel cuvid -c:v h264_cuvid -i input.mp4 -c:a copy -c:v h264_nvenc -b:v 5M output.mp4`

I get the error

> [h264_cuvid @ 0x556eaa3ea780] ***Codec h264_cuvid is not supported***

Here's the output of `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 450.51.05    Driver Version: 450.51.05    CUDA Version: 11.0     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce 940MX       On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   47C    P5    N/A /  N/A |    396MiB /  2004MiB |     22%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
                                                                               
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                                  |
|  GPU   GI   CI        PID   Type   Process name                  GPU Memory |
|        ID   ID                                                   Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0   N/A  N/A      1131      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                 37MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      1883      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                129MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      2175      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell               92MiB |
|    0   N/A  N/A      3649      G   ...AAAAAAAAA= --shared-files      126MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And the output of `ffmpeg`:

```
ffmpeg version git-2020-07-25-7c8ad72 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 9 (Ubuntu 9.3.0-10ubuntu2)
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-cuda-nvcc --enable-libnpp --enable-gpl --enable-libx264 --extra-cflags=-I/usr/local/cuda/include --extra-ldflags=-L/usr/local/cuda/lib64
  libavutil      56. 57.100 / 56. 57.100
  libavcodec     58. 97.102 / 58. 97.102
  libavformat    58. 49.100 / 58. 49.100
  libavdevice    58. 11.101 / 58. 11.101
  libavfilter     7. 87.100 /  7. 87.100
  libswscale      5.  8.100 /  5.  8.100
  libswresample   3.  8.100 /  3.  8.100
  libpostproc    55.  8.100 / 55.  8.100
```

Comment: On Debian I build ffmpeg deb packages with cuda support from the sources, let me know if you're interested.

Comment: `ffmpeg -codecs |grep '\(nvenc\|cuvid\)'` should show some codec with nvenc|cuvid  support ```DEV.LS h264
DEV.L. hevc
DEVIL. mjpeg
DEV.L. mpeg1video
DEV.L. mpeg2video
DEV.L. mpeg4
D.V.L. vc1
DEV.L. vp8
DEV.L. vp9```

Comment: @Alex, I'm pasting part of the output below. When I try these codecs, I get the same error. What command should I use to convert a video? 
`DEV.LS h264                 H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10 (decoders: h264 h264_v4l2m2m h264_cuvid ) (encoders: libx264 libx264rgb h264_nvenc h264_v4l2m2m nvenc nvenc_h264 )`
`DEV.L. hevc                 H.265 / HEVC (High Efficiency Video Coding) (decoders: hevc hevc_v4l2m2m hevc_cuvid ) (encoders: nvenc_hevc hevc_nvenc hevc_v4l2m2m )
DEVIL. mjpeg                Motion JPEG (decoders: mjpeg mjpeg_cuvid )`

Comment: The command you mention in the question works just fine, tested it with a video `Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (h264_nvenc) (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), cuda, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=-1--1, 2000 kb/s, 30 fps, 15360 tbn, 30 tbc (default)`

Comment: Though you're using a ffmpeg version from git while I'm using the one released with Debian/unstable (4.3.1)